# Android live audio streaming via RTP over own IP

Tags: android, audio, rtp, http-streaming

How can I live stream the audio (RTP) of a phone's mic?
I want to serve my stream on my own IP. Like: `rtp://my_sream_ip:8080` (by acting as a server).

**Actually, I think the possible way is to:**

First: Create a server and On click of a button, stream mic's audio to the created server.

Secondly:Then the audio that is being streamed on a url(e.g.: rtp://127.0.0.1:8080) should be streamed in such a way that another APP can live stream audio from that.(receive/play that stream)

I am very sorry for asking such a long question, but I am very much tired for 2 weeks searching everywhere.

Anyone who can provide any code samples/links will be thanked very much!

Comment: HTTP live streaming is functionally streaming yet actually its just a series of file downloads which get rendered on the client ... I wrote a such a client for iOS yet with no iOS specific logic so yes you can do this on android ... I suggest you read the docs on HLS as published from the ISO spec and/or directly from Apple

Comment: @ScottStensland Can you provide me a link?

Answer (score 3):

Its possible but you should have your own AudioStream; to understand it please refer [Android audio streaming with OpenSL ES and the NDK. | The Audio Programming Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20141023183020/http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/)

Then you can stream live audio via HTTP, web service etc.

Please inform me about phases.

Comment: @Doğan Kılıç Can you tell me some steps? I am on Android Studio and I am not expert at git. can you put it altogether and give me a final answer ? please?